# How to do multiple joins when some tables are empty

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to append 'lookup data' to a main record text/description field so it looks something like this:

*This is the Description Text


**LookUpName1:**

LookupValue1

LookupValueN*

This worked fine with `Inner Join` like so

```
Select J.id, Concat('<b>LookUpName</b>:<br>',group_concat(F.LookUpValue SEPARATOR '<br>')) 
from MainTable J Inner Join
     LookUpTable L Inner Join
     LookUpValuesTable F
     On J.ID = L.JobID and F.ID = L.FilterID
Group by J.ID
```

However my goal is to add append multiple Lookup Tables and if I add them to this as Inner Joins I naturally just get those record where both/all the LookupTables have records.

On the other hand when I tried `Join` or `Left Join` I got an error on the `Group by J.ID`.

My goal is to append any of the existing Lookup Table values to all of the Description. Right now all I can achieve is returning appended descriptions which have ALL of the Lookup table values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would work if the `on` clauses were in the "right" place:

```
select J.id,
       Concat('<b>LookUpName</b>:<br>', group_concat(F.LookUpValue separator '<br>')) 
from MainTable J left join
     LookUpTable L
     on J.ID = L.JobID left join
     LookUpValuesTable F
     on F.ID = L.FilterID
group by J.ID;
```

The problem with your query is a MySQL (mis)feature.  The `on` clause is optional for an inner join.  Don't ask me why the MySQL designers thought `inner join` and `cross join` should be syntactically equivalent.  Every other database requires an `on` clause for an `inner join`.  It is easy enough to express a `cross join` using `on 1=1`.

However, the `on` clause is required for the `left join`, so when you switch to a `left join`, the compiler has a problem with the unorthodox syntax.  The real problem is a missing `on` clause; this just happens to show up as "I wasn't expecting a `group by` yet." Using more traditional syntax with each `join` followed by an `on` should fix the problem.

Comment: I think I've got it :| When I do Inner Joins I generally can/do just put all of the `On`s in the same place, but with `Left Join` I need to do each `From Table Left Join On` discretely.

Comment: @user3649739 . . . You should learn to put the `on`s next to the tables being joined.  This makes the queries much easier to follow and debug and is how almost everyone writes them.

Comment: Here is an issue with this even though it works: if I run just one left join I get the proper output for it's `group_concat`: `LUTtype1:<br>LUTtype1_Value1<br>LUTtype1_Value2`. As soon as I add the next left join even though that works as well I know get `LUTtype1:<br>LUTtype1_Value1<br>LUTtype1_Value2<br>LUTtype1_Value1<br>LUTtype1_Value2`.

Comment: @user3649739 . . . You should ask *another* question.  This question is about syntax, not the results of the query.  The other question should include sample data and desired results.